# Can't add form widgets to main.xml file Graphical Layout

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and I wonder why I can't drag and drop things like buttons to the display in the main.xml Graphical Layout? It seems like it's locked or something else that I can't figure out on myself. Help is preciated! Thanks!

EDIT: This is my code in xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/textview"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:text="@string/hello"
 />
```

Comment: Make sure to update Android. If you updated eclipse recently, they did some major changes in 8.x that requires some changes on Androids part.

Comment: But I have just installed the Android SDK. The problem is that I could add buttons just a couple of hours ago, but now it seems like it's impossible! Could it depond on something else? I'm sure it's just me doing something wrong

Comment: what is the code in your main.xml file?

Comment: I added my code if that could be any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not able to do so because you don't have a [Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) in your XML. [Given here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#write) is an example as to how to build a basic layout. You can also refer to the [Relative Layout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) or [Linear Layout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html) for more details, as these are widely used layouts.

Given below is the sample code for your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can replace `Linear Layout` with `Relative Layout` at your convenience. But do keep in mind that you *can't* use the graphical layout without having a layout. To drag and drop a layout, refer the image below:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If that's your code, then it seems that you might be trying to drag elements into the TextView since it is filling the entire layout. Try to remove the TextView and see if you are then able to drag and drop elements again. Either that or change it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/textview"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/hello"
 />
```

Comment: Isn't that the same code that I already have? No, it didn't work whis this new code

Comment: No, I changed it so the height didn't fill_parent. I suspected the fact that your TextView completely fill_parent in both directions, it was causing the problem. Have you tried removing the TextView?

Comment: Yes I have tried to remove it, then I got no screen to drag and drop att all!?

Comment: Create a new project from scratch. Ensure these symptoms are reproducible and get an idea on where the problem is coming from. If it works in another project, then you can assume it's something within your current project causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I am a begginer Android Studio to. I have same problem about drag and drop in design screen (in GUI). I solve the problem by using  "***res/layout/content_main.xml***" (left side of the screen).  It works! but ı am not sure that is it the right way :)))

Answer (score -1):

Drag and drop the elements onto the Outline area instead of the display itself.Worked for me.